# How do I use cookies to remember a button toggle or class in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

How can I use cookies to remember whether dark mode is turned on and keep it active?

Here's my code:

```js
$(".inner-switch").on("click", function() {
  if ($("body").hasClass("dark")) {
    $("body").removeClass("dark");
    $(".inner-switch").text("OFF");
  } else {
    $("body").addClass("dark");
    $(".inner-switch").text("ON");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 50rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0.9375rem;
}

small {
  font-style: italic;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  align-self: center;
}

.switch {
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin: 0.9375rem;
}

.inner-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  width: 3.125rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.1875rem;
  margin-left: 0.3125rem;
}

.dark,
.dark * {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  border-color: #e6e6e6;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">Dark mode:
  <span class="inner-switch">OFF</span>
</div>
<h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amete</h1>
<article>
  <h1>consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
  <p><small>Morbi hendrerit accumsan vulputate.m</small></p>
  <p>...</p>
</article>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: So you want the dark mode to stay toggled whenever the user refreshes the page and/or exit the page/tab and navigate back to it within the same browser session?

Comment: Yeah thats what I meant to say, sorry

Comment: I recommend if you have time you look into using localStorage as a solution for this problem

Comment: Here is a working example using your code: https://codepen.io/xcy7e/pen/PooGKeZ
I moved the darkmode functionality in a separate function and split the cookie-stuff in a document.ready function while the button trigger simply uses the darkMode functions.

Comment: You might also be interested in the `prefers-color-scheme` media query that lets the user control dark mode settings system-wide.

Comment: @Jonathan this worked thank you!

Comment: @Hayden I updated my answer so it explains each part of the code for better understandig. It now uses the code I provided in the working example on codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set cookies with plain javascript using `document.cookie`.
Regarding your example code I'd recommend moving the darkMode functionality (enable/disable) in separate functions. Then read the cookie value when the pageload finished and call the functions depending on the cookie value.

---

**Implement cookie logic**

```
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    // the following code allows multiple cookie values and splits them apart
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
function eraseCookie(name) {   
    document.cookie = name+'=; Max-Age=-99999999;';  
}
```

---

**DarkMode functionality in separate functions**

```
function enableDarkMode() {
    $( "body" ).addClass( "dark" );
    $( ".inner-switch" ).text( "ON" );
    setCookie('darkMode',"1",7);
}

function disableDarkMode() {
  $( "body" ).removeClass( "dark" );
  $( ".inner-switch" ).text( "OFF" );
  setCookie('darkMode',"0",7);
}
```

**Button click-event using the darkMode-functions**

```
$( ".inner-switch" ).on("click", function() {
    if( $( "body" ).hasClass( "dark" )) {
      disableDarkMode();
    } else {
      enableDarkMode();
    }
});
```

**Read the cookie when the page has finished loading** (plain js)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  var darkMode = getCookie('darkMode');
  if (darkMode == "1") {
      // use darkmode
      enableDarkMode();
  } else {
      // no darkmode
      disableDarkMode();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

While Jonathan's answer does answer your question well, I do want to show how this can also be done with localStorage, as a comment has pointed out as a potential solution

```
$(document).on('load', () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('dark-mode') === 'true') {
        $('body').addClass('dark')
        $('.inner-switch').text('OFF')
    }
});

$('.inner-switch').on('click', () => {
    let $body = $('body');
    let $switch = $('.inner-switch');

    if ($body.hasClass("dark")) {
        localStorage.setItem('dark-mode', 'false');
        $body.removeClass("dark");
        $switch.text("OFF");
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('dark-mode', 'true');
        $body.addClass("dark");
        $switch.text("ON");
    }
});
```

This is a little simpler to implement than cookies, and will give you similar persistence

Comment: Thanks, where would I place this in the html?

Comment: Just adding to your JavaScript file would be enough

Comment: Although localStorage is a good alternative especially in this case, keep in mind that it is **not supported by anything before**: IE 8, Firefox 3.5, Safari 4, Chrome 4, Opera 10.5, iOS 2.0, Android 2.0